# How to scrape data at once when the URL changes in multiple positions (RStudio)?

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping

Currently I'm scraping data from a link, with one variable changing the page

```
scrape <- lapply(1:5, function(x){

  url <- paste0("https://www.website.com/yr=2022&nat=all&pg=",x) %>% read_html()

  table <- xml_find_all(url, "//table") %>% html_table

  data <- table[[4]]
})

db <- data.table::rbindlist(scrape) #combine table
```

**But I'd like to be able to modify the URL in several places, to scrape it at once. Namely changing the year in addition the the page numbers.** Editing string values would be helpful too, if it's simple to do in the method.

I think paste0 might come into it. Something like

```
url <- paste0("https://www.website.com/yr=",x,
                                     "&nat=",y,
                                     "&pg=",z)
```

but I'm not sure. lapply won't take more than one vector when I tried to create a multivariable function, so I presume that's not what I should use here.

Anyone got an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could build a table of urls, like below (you'd need to put in your valid values of year, nat, and pg. Below I've made some fake values (years from 2019 to 2021, nat values a,b,c, and pg from 1 to 5)

```
library(data.table)

urls = data.table(year=c(2019,2020,2021), nat=c("a","b","c"))
urls = data.table(expand.grid(urls))[rep(1:.N,each=5)] %>% 
  .[, pg:=rep(1:5,9)] %>% 
  .[, url:=paste0(
    "https://www.website.com/yr=",year,"&nat=",nat,"&pg=",pg
    )]
```

This is what the first six rows look like

```
head(urls)

   year nat pg                                        url
1: 2019   a  1 https://www.website.com/yr=2019&nat=a&pg=1
2: 2019   a  2 https://www.website.com/yr=2019&nat=a&pg=2
3: 2019   a  3 https://www.website.com/yr=2019&nat=a&pg=3
4: 2019   a  4 https://www.website.com/yr=2019&nat=a&pg=4
5: 2019   a  5 https://www.website.com/yr=2019&nat=a&pg=5
6: 2020   a  1 https://www.website.com/yr=2020&nat=a&pg=1
```

Then make a function that takes a url and pulls the data you need

```
scrape <- function(url) {
  url <- read_html(url) 
  table <- xml_find_all(url, "//table") %>% html_table
  data <- table[[4]]
  return(data)
}
```

And apply the function to each row

```
urls[,.(scrape(url)), by=1:nrow(urls)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Testing it out but having some issues

**1:**  it repeated lines but that was easily cleaned up with `unique.data.frame()` (for future readers)

**2:** one issue I'm still having is the `urls` breaks when I increase the years, which I plan to do over time. Not quite understanding the function of rep() and the numbers were chosen? Is there a way to set them so it's malleable to change or how would I have to edit it to make it work?

**3:** Also, urls[,scrape(url)] gives `Error: x must be a string of length 1` Is it meant to be `url` throughout in the previous codeblock

Comment: I just made up the urls. You can and should make your own data.table of urls, or just put them in a vector of urls and try `lapply(urls, scrape)`.  If you do keep them in a data.table, try `urls[,.(scrape(url)), by=1:nrow(urls)]`

Comment: regarding the rep, all i did was make up a set of years and nat values, used expand grid to create all nine possibilities (3 years x 3 nat) and then repeated those 9 rows 5 times each to get 45 rows, and add sequence 1 to 5, nine times so that there would be 3x3x5=45 unique urls.. obviously those are not the actual urls, because i don't know what years, nats, or pages you are interested in scraping

Comment: hope that helps.. let me know if I'm still not being clear